# Object becomes nil after init inside block

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

Here's my code:

```
    __block UIButton buttonOne;
    __block UIButton buttonTwo;
    - (UIView *)addressOptionView
    {
        if (!_addressOptionView) {
            _addressOptionView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame), addressButtonArray.count * BasedAdditionForSegment)];

            void (^setupButton)(UIButton *, NSString *, NSInteger) = ^
            void (UIButton *button, NSString *title, NSInteger idx) {
                if (!button)
                    button = [[UIButton alloc] init];
                button.frame = ({
                    CGRect frame = _addressOptionView.bounds;
                    frame.origin.x += 20;
                    frame.size.width -= 40;
                    frame.origin.y = idx * BasedAdditionForSegment;
                    frame.size.height = BasedAdditionForSegment;
                    frame;
                });
                [button setTitle:title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            };
            setupButton(buttonOne, addressButtonArray[0], 0);
            setupButton(buttonTwo, addressButtonArray[1], 1);

            DebugLog(@"%@", buttonOne);
            [_addressOptionView addSubview:buttonOne];
            [_addressOptionView addSubview:buttonTwo];
        }
        return _addressOptionView;
    }
```

`buttonOne` and `buttonTwo` is not properties.

After I call `addressOptionView getter`, these two buttons are deallocated immediately, thus they don't show up in the view (I guess, nil when `NSLog`).

I changed the `setupButton` block to `@property` and it doesn't work either.
Changing two button to `@property` doesn't work too.

However, when I change the `setupButton` block to

`UIButton * (^setupButton)(NSString *, NSInteger)`

Two buttons do show up, but I cannot access them later in other methods (`nil` already).

Can somebody give me a brief explanation about what do I do wrong ? How do I make it work ?
Thanks.

Comment: Why are you declaring `buttonOne` and `buttonTwo` outside of a method?

Comment: it's just for easier view, they're actually declared in the class' private category.

Comment: If they are instance variables, why are they declared with `__block`?

Comment: The pointer into your block is passed by value. When the buttons come in `nil`, the assignment to the ivars never happens. You need to pass the address of the ivars in if you want to assign to them. The assignment to the block's local button variable is lost when the block returns.

Comment: @rmaddy because I'm not sure about it, I tested both ways with and without it. Seem likes it doesn't have any effect at all.

Comment: @JasonCoco can you give some code pls ?

Comment: @PhamHoan: `__block` can only be used with local variables. Anywhere else it is meaningless.

Answer (score 3):

```
@implementation SomeObject {
  // do not make these __block types
  UIButton* _buttonOne;
  UIButton* _buttonTwo;
}

- (UIView *)addressOptionView
{
  // most of method removed for brevity, see question
  void (^setupButton)(UIButton*__autoreleasing*, NSString *, NSInteger) = ^
   void (UIButton*__autoreleasing*button, NSString *title, NSInteger idx) {
    NSAssert( button, @"Must not pass nil reference as button" );
    UIButton* localButton = *button;
    if (!localButton) {
      // continue to work on the more convenient localButton, but make sure
      // that the button reference is written to the ivar...
      localButton = *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    }
    // other button setup clipped
  };
  // compiler will generate strong stack-allocated temporary variable here
  // to deal with autoreleasing assignment, but make sure ivars are not
  // __block class
  setupButton(&_buttonOne, addressButtonArray[0], 0);
  setupButton(&_buttonTwo, addressButtonArray[1], 1);

  DebugLog(@"%@", _buttonOne);
  [_addressOptionView addSubview:_buttonOne];
  [_addressOptionView addSubview:_buttonTwo];

  // top-most branch was clipped for this example
  return _addressOptionView;
}
```

Comment: better to return UIButton instead of mucking around with pointers

Comment: @BryanChen I agree, I would have done the whole thing completely differently myself, using weak ivars that are set after whatever this view is setup and created, but that wasn't the question and anyone stuck with legacy code or whatever that doesn't understand that pointer variables are passed by value might find a solution here.

Comment: Thanks Jason, I agree too, I would like to have another answer which is more efficient. I'm not familliar with working with pointers and I'm kind of stuck with `passing address to non-local object to __autoreleasing parameter for write-back` (not sure where I did wrong).

Answer (score 1):

This line is the problem...

```
button = [[UIButton alloc] init];
```

Once you do that, the ***copy*** of the ***reference*** to your button that you passed into your block is now pointing to a different location in memory. This does **not** change where the original button reference is pointing as you are only changing where the ***copied*** button reference is pointing. Remember, objective-c is pass by value!